# concurrent msync on a separate thread

Tags: linux, shared-memory, mmap

In a mainstream linux/x64 environment, I've mapped a part of a file using *mmap* and keep writing to the mmap'ed range in a while loop from *ThreadA*. I call msync every second on the same range from a separate *ThreadB*.

1. while msync is going on, if Thread A writes to a page that's under I/O due to msync - will it block?
2. if Thread A doesn't block, will subsequent calls to msync pick up the re-dirtied page and write the data to disk?
3. address range aside would fdatasync behave any differently?

Comment: Sample code would make this question more clear.

Comment: @chux really you think mmap followed by an msync on a separate thread requires sample code?

Comment: My comment was not on requirements.